# Meteor app does not download data on iOS in production, but works in TestFlight

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

My Meteor iOS app does not download data through Galaxy. The exact same build works find in TestFlight, while the same code, packaged for Android, works fine.

Also, building the app to Xcode, running it on my own device or any of the simulators works fine. As does deploying it through TestFlight. But, when pushed to production, and accepted by Apple, it no longer works. This has been confirmed on two iOS devices.

The web-based version at myappurl.meteorapp.com also works fine.

My app is hosted on Galaxy, but my database is on mlab. This is my settings.json:

```
{
    "galaxy.meteor.com": {
        "env": {
            "ROOT_URL": "https://myappurl.meteorapp.com",
            "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://user:password@instance.mlab.com:port/db"
        }
    }
}
```

This happened with a version of my app that incorporated a range of changes, but actually also with fewer packages than before.

I'm a bit at a loss here. How to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

My app also had moved from one major release to another. With the latest release, I was using a different ROOT_URL. This worked fine, as it should. Except, it seems, when moving the binary from TestFlight to production, when the app suddenly again tried to connect to the old ROOT_URL.

To resolve this, I uploaded a new version of my app that relied on the old ROOT_URL. The major downside being, obviously, that it broke the experience of those who had not yet upgraded to the latest version of the app.